# Spark DataFrame column with comma separated list of other columns that needs to be updated with values given in another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case trying to solve in Spark DataFrames.
Column "col4" is comma separated string consisting of other columns names that needs to be updated with string values given in column col5.

```
+----+----+----+---------+----+
|col1|col2|col3|     col4|col5|
+----+----+----+---------+----+
|   A|   B|   C|col2,col3| X,Y|
|   P|   Q|   R|     col1|   Z|
|   I|   J|   K|col1,col3| S,T|
+----+----+----+---------+----+
```

After transformation - Resulting DataFrame should looks like below. 
How can I achieve this?

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   X|   Y|
|   Z|   Q|   R|
|   S|   J|   T|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: col4 and col5 are both Arraytypes/lists?

Comment: col4 and col5 both are string type. For example-  for first row col4 would have value like "col2,col3". And, col5 have "X,Y".

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi - Seems like map_from_arrays is not member of function in Scala.  <console>:34: error: value map_from_arrays is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.functions

Comment: it is , https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@map_from_arrays(keys:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,values:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column ... what spark version are you using?

Comment: ahh...I am on Spark 2.3

Comment: okay, you are just .1 short, thats unfortunate. I will try to update solution based on your version. but will also recommend you to update spark version.

Answer (score 1):

Basically i **created 2 arrays of col4 and col5** and then used **map_from_arrays** to create a map, then made a column of **those col1,col2,col3 using the map**  and then used **when,otherwise**(*when isNotNull*) clauses to change your columns in place.

(**spark2.4+**)

**Data**

```
df.show()

+----+----+----+---------+----+
|col1|col2|col3|     col4|col5|
+----+----+----+---------+----+
|   A|   B|   C|col2,col3| X,Y|
|   P|   Q|   R|     col1|   Z|
|   I|   J|   K|col1,col3| S,T|
+----+----+----+---------+----+
```

**%scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, map_from_arrays, split, when}

df.withColumn("col6", map_from_arrays(split($"col4",","),split($"col5",","))).drop("col4","col5")
.select($"col1",$"col2",$"col3",col("col6.col1").alias("col1_"),col("col6.col2").alias("col2_"),col("col6.col3").alias("col3_"))
.withColumn("col1", when(col("col1_").isNotNull, col("col1_")).otherwise($"col1"))
.withColumn("col2", when(col("col2_").isNotNull,col("col2_")).otherwise($"col2"))
.withColumn("col3",when(col("col3_").isNotNull,col("col3_")).otherwise($"col3"))
.drop("col1_","col2_","col3_")
.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   X|   Y|
|   Z|   Q|   R|
|   S|   J|   T|
+----+----+----+
```

**%python**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("col6", F.map_from_arrays(F.split("col4",','),F.split("col5",','))).drop("col4","col5")\
.select("col1","col2","col3",F.col("col6.col1").alias("col1_"),F.col("col6.col2").alias("col2_"),F.col("col6.col3").alias("col3_"))\
.withColumn("col1", F.when(F.col("col1_").isNotNull(), F.col("col1_")).otherwise(F.col("col1")))\
.withColumn("col2", F.when(F.col("col2_").isNotNull(),F.col("col2_")).otherwise(F.col("col2")))\
.withColumn("col3",F.when(F.col("col3_").isNotNull(),F.col("col3_")).otherwise(F.col("col3")))\
.drop("col1_","col2_","col3_")\
.show()


+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   X|   Y|
|   Z|   Q|   R|
|   S|   J|   T|
+----+----+----+
```

**UPDATE:**
This will work for **spark 2.0+**(*without map_from_array*):

(you could make a scala udf and apply similar logic, hope it helps)

**%python**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


@udf("map<string,string>")
def as_dict(x):
    return dict(zip(*x)) if x else None


df.withColumn("col6", F.array(F.split(("col4"),','),F.split(("col5"),','))).drop("col4","col5")\
.withColumn("col6", as_dict("col6")).select("col1","col2","col3",F.col("col6.col1").alias("col1_"),F.col("col6.col2").alias("col2_"),F.col("col6.col3").alias("col3_"))\
.withColumn("col1", F.when(F.col("col1_").isNotNull(), F.col("col1_")).otherwise(F.col("col1")))\
.withColumn("col2", F.when(F.col("col2_").isNotNull(),F.col("col2_")).otherwise(F.col("col2")))\
.withColumn("col3",F.when(F.col("col3_").isNotNull(),F.col("col3_")).otherwise(F.col("col3")))\
.drop("col1_","col2_","col3_")\
.show()
```

Comment: @ Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi - Thanks for solutions. I build the solution in Scala using your approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 2.4+**

If the columns are not only 3, then it should be scalable for more columns. I have made this code to expand easily.

```
val cols = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")

val df1 = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
val df2 = cols.foldLeft(
    df1.withColumn("col6", explode(arrays_zip(split($"col4", ","),split($"col5", ","))))
             .groupBy("id").pivot($"col6.0").agg(first($"col6.1"))
) {(df, c) => df.withColumnRenamed(c, c + "2")}

cols.foldLeft(df1.join(df2, "id")) {(df, c) => df.withColumn(c, coalesce(col(c + "2"), col(c)))}
  .select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)
  .show
```

The result is:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   X|   Y|
|   Z|   Q|   R|
|   S|   J|   T|
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

This a problem which can be easilly handled with the `map` function of RDDs:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType}

val targetColumns = df.columns.take(3) // we assume that the final df should contain 3 first elements. If not feel free to modify this accordingly to your requirements

val updatedRDD = df.rdd.map{ r => 
  val keys = r.getAs[String]("col4").split(",")
  val values = r.getAs[String]("col5").split(",")
  val mapping = keys.zip(values).toMap[String, String] // i.e: Map(col2 -> X, col3 -> Y)

  val updatedValues = targetColumns.map{c =>   
    if(keys.contains(c))
      mapping(c)
    else
      r.getAs[String](c)
  }

  Row(updatedValues:_*)
}

val schema = StructType(targetColumns.map{c => StructField(c, StringType, true)})
spark.createDataFrame(updatedRDD, schema).show(false)

// +----+----+----+
// |col1|col2|col3|
// +----+----+----+
// |A   |X   |Y   |
// |Z   |Q   |R   |
// |S   |J   |T   |
// +----+----+----+
```

We create a map using `col4->keys, col5->values` which is used to create the final `Row` that will be returned.

Comment: @ Alexandros Biratsis - Thanks for coming forward.